# Can I find constants in a function?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Let's say, I have a function with a constant, e.g. $y(x)=x+c$, and a condition $y(0) = 5$.
I want to type in something like `Solve[{y[x]=x+c, y[0] =5}, {c}]` and get the value of a constant. Is there a way to do it in Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Do you mean $y \color{red}{'}(x)=x+c$ (otherwise it's not a DE)?

Comment: Yeah, I might need y' as well, e.g. [{y[x] = some function, y[0] = a, y'[x] = b}, {c1, c2}]

Comment: Ok, I'm very spooked. How did it take you 1 second to reply to my comment?

Comment: I know, I've already found the general solution. Just need to find the values of the constants.

Comment: There is definitely a way to do that, I had a hw assignment last spring where I had to do exactly this. I won't be home for a few hours, but once I get home I can send you the Syntax to calculate something like this. (If nobody else has answered the question before then)

Comment: I think if you define the function `y[_x,_c] = x + c` you can call `Solve[ y[0,c] == 5, c]` to find the parameter `c`.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! people suggested something similar here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59838/find-constants-in-a-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your function, to use your example:

```
y[x_] := x + c
```

and then simple solve it using the initial condition:

```
In[10]:= Solve[y[0] == 5, c]

Out[11]= {{c -> 5}}
```

The title of your question is a bit confusing, since this doesn't really have much to do with ODEs. :)

Comment: I was working with ODEs, but I totally agree with you, changed the title and the question

Answer (score 1):

you can enter y(0)=2 for example enter:
y'+y=0,y(0)=2
i think this is solve your problem.
this is for online mathmatica(www.wolframalpha.com)

Comment: It will use some kind of DSolve under the hood. I don't need to solve the ODE, I already have the general solution

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentioning DSolve works similarly to Solve, and that NSolve will give you a numerical representation of a number rather than a symbolic. for example, say I want to find the roots of  $x^{2} - 2 = 0$

```
Solve[x^2 - 2, x] == 0
```

will return $\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$, but NSolve will return

```
{{x -> -1.41421}, {x -> 1.41421}}
```

Also, I think DSolve uses Solve under the hood, not the other way around